# com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'name' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-platform

I am trying to update my database using an update statement, when I am trying to do this it is showing me an error...these are the exceptions I could find here.

com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'name' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1600)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1695)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3020)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1008)
    at data.changing.jButton1ActionPerformed(changing.java:125)
    at data.changing.access$000(changing.java:21)
    at data.changing$1.actionPerformed(changing.java:62)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: Is `name` a VARCHAR(x) and your `String.length()` > x maybe?

Answer (score 4):

you can solve this error to adding property in Jboss datasource like
jdbc:mysql://localhost:1189/dbName?jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8

you can add jdbc truncation false to solve this error.But your data will be truncated based on value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because size of that coloumn is small then the data you are trying to insert so change the datatype of that coloumn to a larger datatype (for eg in place of char use varchar..) then there will be no problem

Answer (score 0):

You are having this exception probably because you are trying to update a column with a string that is longer than your SQL column length defined in a create statement. Make sure also if you have proper character encoding set in your database, while saving operation with a shorter or equal string (than column definition) may end with such exception if you have special marks in it.